# wrap youtube video inside responsive image "frame", using LazyYT.js for lazy-loading

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, youtube, responsive-design

first here's a fiddle of my current code. Please click the "play" button on the video to see thee issue I am encountering.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pr3fix/1bc83mhd/1/

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to place a YouTube video over an image of a laptop, so that it looks like the video is "playing" on the laptop screen. This needs to be responsive, so when the browser is resized, the video/laptop are scaled properly.

I also need to use [LazyYT.js](https://github.com/tylerpearson/lazyYT), a jQuery plugin which loads only a thumbnail of the video until the user clicks it, then the entire iframe is loaded.

**What isn't working:**

Once the iframe is on the screen my code is doing what I want (the youtube video 
is placed nicely over the screen). However, I need the pre-iframe lazyYT thumbnail to do the same thing. As you can see in the fiddle, it does not display properly until you click the thumbnail (load the iframe), then everything is fine.

**question:**

How can I get LazyYT.js to display my thumbnail in the same way as I am currently displaying the iframe?

**code: (note: using jQuery + Zurb Foundation + SASS):**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns front-page" role="main">
        <div class="row content-section sneakpeek hide-for-small-only">
            <div class="section-title">
                 <h2>ASC Online Sneak Peek</h2>

            </div>
            <!-- .section-title -->
            <div class="row vidrow">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="vidwrapper">
                        <div class="framewrapper">
                            <div class="lazyYT" data-youtube-id="5DHYe4dhjXw">loading...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .row -->
        </div>
        <!-- .content-section -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**SASS:**

```
.front-page .content-section.sneakpeek {

  padding: 1rem 3rem 3rem 3rem;

  .vidrow {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3rem;
  }

  .vidwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1034px;
    max-height: 543px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .framewrapper {
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 25px;
      padding-bottom: 67.5%;
      height: 0;

      .lazyYT-container {
        background: transparent;
        position: initial;
      }
      iframe {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/vq812Tr.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        padding: 11.9% 15.5% 14.8%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
} // .front-page .content-section.sneakpeek
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('.lazyYT').lazyYT();
```

Comment: Your fiddle is just showing a blank output page for me.

Comment: To me too, exactly like the two fiddles in the answer. Something must be offline, or has changed URL meanwhile :) BTW +1 for making me know LazyYT :)

Comment: The output is designed to be hidden on small screens -- try making the output area of the fiddle larger and you will see the content :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `background`, `background-size`, and `padding` properties from the iframe to the .vidwrapper so that these apply even when the video is not displayed yet. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4mo4taa/).

**update**: This should work correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/eyx8yvLz/1/. The aspect ratio of the video does not fit the background, so I had to adjust that a little bit.

Comment: you haven't fit the thumbnail inside of the grey container ( must stay within the screen ), and it also breaks on resize. If you can help me figure out how to fix those issues the +rep is yours.

Comment: Updated version is much much better (thanks!) however there's still a sliver of background showing through at the bottom of the video, and when the screen is scaled up, it grows more noticeable.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do about that. The video does not match the aspect ratio of the laptop, and there isn't a good way to change the video's aspect ratio. I would suggest using a different laptop image that has a frame the same aspect ratio as the video.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, I was hoping to get by without having to modify assets... I'm going to leave this open for a few days, if I don't receive any better submissions by then I'll give it to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is none of your fiddles showing anything but a WSOD ?

Comment: Add small screen sizes, the content is designed to be hidden. You may have to increase the size of the result box a little bit.